# Django application using UTC throughout

Tags: python, django, datetime, utc

I am building a Django application that will be using UTC for all time stamps and datetime fields. The users (operators of a networks of environmental research stations) are trained to enter times in UTC (GMT) and the server as well as the users' work desktop/laptop computers are set to UTC with no daylight saving time adjustment.

In `settings.py`, I could set `TIME_ZONE` to `None`, but do not want to rely on server time if I can help it.

How would you set Django's configuration settings?

Comment: Why not use the GMT/UTC/UT time-zone?  Also known as "GMT-0"?  What's wrong with that?  It's called "UCT Etc/UCT" in the Django docs.

Comment: OK, I was about to say that quite obviously this would be preferable, Django refers to the Wikipedia list of named time zones, which doesn't have this, but you are completely correct that the settings.py documentation (as opposed to the boilerplate in the default settings file created by Django) sends me to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE, which has these. If you would like to add this as a solution, I'd happily accept it, otherwise I'll delete the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong on this (I've only partially updated a project to correctly handle timezones), but I believe that the `TIME_ZONE` variable is only used by the Postgres backend (determined by grepping the source). So, if you're not using Postgres, it doesn't really matter what you use… And if you are using Postgres, you can use `"UTC"` ([relevant documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE)).

Comment: The time zone can be used anywhere in the stdlib, via the TZ environment variable (Django sets it and calls tzset). That said, UTC everywhere should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#time-zone

It's called "UCT Etc/UCT" in the [Django docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datetime-keywords.html#DATETIME-TIMEZONE-SET-TABLE).